# Angular Routing Causing infinite loop when using parameters in url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting infinite loop when trying to access a parameterized url in angular.

Here is the code.

> app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");

var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.use('/',function(req,res){

res.sendFile("./home.html");
});


app.listen("4467", function() {

    console.log("Started listening at port 4467 new");
});
```

> home.html

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script src="a02.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
Hello Homepage
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> a02.js

```
    var app = angular.module("testApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/test/:a', {
    templateUrl: './sum.html',
    controller: 'sum'
  })
  .when("/",{
    templateUrl:"./a02.html"
  })
  .otherwise({
    template:"Otherwise"
  });

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
}]);

app.controller('sum', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log("I am controller "+ $routeParams.a);
  $scope.a = $routeParams.a;
  $scope.b = $routeParams.b;
});
```

> a02.html

```
Hello there
  <hr>
  <script>  console.log("Getting called again");</script>
  <a href="test/10">Click Me </a>
```

My requirement is when I click on the Click Me link it should replace the existing ng-view template i.e a02.html to sum.html.

> sum.html

```
<div>

 Value of a: {{a}} </br>
 Value of b: {{b}}

</div>
```

But I am getting infinite loop when click on Click Me link.Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: maybe that's just a detail and i'm wrong, but try with `<a href="/test/10">Click Me </a>` (with a '/' before test).. if i am right you get the otherwise case

Comment: @Kaddath I tried but it didn't work. Getting same result again. :-(

Comment: if it's not too late, I highly recommend using [the defacto ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)